# Clean up terminal misstakes

Tags: bash, macos, homebrew

I am new to the terminal and was trying to install Java.
Also attempted to use homebrew, have since uninstalled.

Now everytime I open the terminal I have three lines

```
-bash: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew: No such file or directory

-bash: nexport: command not found

-bash: nexport: command not found
```

How do i remove?
Thanks

Comment: Some paths that the homebrew set need to be corrected, but you will have to search where this is coming from. Could be `bash_profile` or `bash_rc`

Comment: I'm sorry, I am total newbie. don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find the Cause

First you should find the source of those commands that are automatically executed every time you log in. Usually there are files that are being executed after every login, depending on your OS it can be a bash script like `bashrc` in your home directory.

So first try to find the file where these commands are executed but fail:

```
cd ~ && grep -rnw 'nexport'
```

This should give you the **file where `nexport` is executed** like **`/home/user/bash_profile`**

If it does not find any file try this:

```
cd / && grep -nwirl 'nexport'  2>&-
```

This searches the whole system for **`nexport`** and prints all files where it occurs. (*the extra parameter `il` will suppress all `access-denied` errors)*

**Same for `brew`** (obviously)

---

### Change affected file(s)

If you found a file, for example lets say its `/home/user/bashrc` *assuming you have rights to write this file*

**type:**

```
nano /home/user/bashr
```

to start editing this file using the easy-to-use, mostly preinstalled `nano-editor`

When editing the file type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to start `search mode` and type `nexport` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It should jump to the line where `nexport` occurs. If it's the line you want to remove just go to its beginning and add a `#`.

**Example:**

`/home/user/bash_rc@line:72`

```
nexport foo/bar
```

**change to:**

```
#nexport foo/bar
```

to comment it out (always better than removing)

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to save and try re-login.

---

Answer (score 0):

When you installed Homebrew and then some of its packages, several configuration files have probably been modified. You need to restore them. Look maybe at `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/Users/<yourself>/.bashrc` (replace `<yourself>` by your username), `/Users/<yourself>/.bash_profile` and `/Users/<yourself>/.profile`.

How to check? Try something like this:

```
$ grep -El '(brew|nexport)' /etc/{bashrc,profile} ~/{.bashrc,.bash_profile,.profile}
```

If something shows up you found the culprit. By the way, did you search the Homebrew documentation for "uninstall"?